# Xamarin Forms gRPC Client returns exception Grpc.Core.RpcException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, soap, grpc

I have in a solution three projects.
The first is a `gRPC` server, which in turn calls another `SOAP` web service.

The second is a console app for testing the service, and it works perfectly.

Main method in Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://localhost:5001";

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World! ");
    Console.Read();

    Console.WriteLine($"Doing request at: {url}");
    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(url);
    var client = new Session.SessionClient(channel);

    var response = client.CreateSession(
        new CreateRequest
        {
            Utente = "{my user}",
            Password = "{my password}"
        });

    Console.WriteLine($"UUID: {response.Uuid}");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Instead, running the same method in Xamarin.Forms the request fail, and it returns a

> Grpc.Core.RpcException when I execute Client.CreateSession(...)

Exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Network subsystem is down SocketException: Network subsystem is down", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Network subsystem is down ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network subsystem is down
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:65 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:84 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:385 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:543 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
  at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall2[TRequest,TResponse].RunCall (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Nullable1[T] timeout) [0x00261] in /_/src/Grpc.Net.Client/Internal/GrpcCall.cs:456 ")'
```

Login.xaml.cs in Xamarin Forms project:

```
private void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "https://localhost:5001";

            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(url);
            var client = new Session.SessionClient(channel);

            var response = client.CreateSession(
                new CreateRequest
                {
                    Utente = "{my user}",
                    Password = "{my password}"
                });

            try
            {
                lblRequestResult.Text = $"UUID: {response.Uuid}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblRequestResult.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: do not use `localhost`.  Use the actual IP or FQDN of the server

Comment: The console app is running on your pc, and also accesses `"https://localhost:5001"`? But xamarin you are running android emulator? If so, google `android emulator bridge network to localhost`. If not, explain more about the setup. Something must be different between the environment xamarin is running in, compared to the console app.